# Opening Password Protected Workbooks Only Works One PC

Tags: excel, vba

tldr; Password protected workbooks require a typed password on colleagues PC but not mine.
I have a macro which runs through a mastersheet linking to external workbooks. The process is:

1. it opens the workbook via link in cell
2. iterates on the workbook
3. save and close
4. onto next in list

The workbooks which are opened all have the same password and using:

```
Workbooks.Open
```

with

```
Password:="password", WriteResPassword:="password"
```

works fine on my PC but the macro requires the password to be typed when I try running on a colleagues PC.

Google hasn't been much help so far. Could anyone help explain why the code types the password on mine but somehow doesn't on a different PC please. All help is appreciated greatly.

Comment: Where does the macro live? Specifically, which module does the code exist within? Is it in the workbook, worksheet, or a module? Did you accidentally save the code within a personal macro workbook that only exists on your computer?

Comment: Hi HackSlash, it's in a module in my personal workbook, which was then exported to my colleague's personal workbook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workbook specific macros should live inside the workbook that they do work upon.

Move the VBA module to the master workbook that opens the child workbooks. Test the code there and see if it works between different PCs.

Comment: Thank you so much, this works. Is there / what is the reason why it's fine in my personal workbook but not on their personal workbook? It's pointing to the same shared file on a shared drive?

Comment: There are many reasons that are hard to diagnose remotely. I would need to see what the VBE window looks like on both PCs, and the full code. The rule of thumb is that the only code you should put in your personal workbook is generic functions that can be used anywhere. If your code has any hard coded paths that's a good indicator that it's workbook specific code. Event code must be placed in the sheet or workbook where the event occurs. You need to use modules for globally public procedures.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks again for the help you've done me a big favour